# What is a "Binyan Bayis fund"?

Tags: marriage, tzedakah-charity

Sorry, but, yet another unfamiliar marriage-related question...

One of my distant cousin's daughter is engaged. Her mother told me that in lieu of sending gifts towards a bridal registry, she has asked people to donate to a "Binyan Bayis Fund." I'm familiar with a "hachnosat kallah" fund, but, generally, the ones that I know are public funds where the collected donations are allocated to brides in some way.

I'm assuming that this "Binyan Bayis fund" may be similar, but, I gather that this is a private fund specifically for this bride. This is the first time that I am hearing this term.

Is someone familiar with what this is? Is this a minhag in certain communities? Is one expected to donate physical gifts or only money? Is there any suggested / average amount that people donate?

Comment: It sounds like its just a cute name (based on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84677/8775)) for raising money. While it has a Hebrew name, I wouldnt assume there is anything Jewish about this.

Comment: @mevaqesh it definitely is based on that definition of the word "bayit". But, as I've not heard of this before, I wonder if this is becoming a new trend as the Shidduch resume has become, or is this an idea that my cousin invented.

Comment: What does some trend have to do with Judaism? Seems like Jews; not Judaism.

Comment: @mevaqesh Agree. But, again, I don't know what this even is. It could be a revived minhag, for all you and I know.

Comment: By that reasoning everything done by Jews is on topic. Since they *could* Have to do with Judaism. Even random non Jewish practices *could* have to do with Judaism...

Comment: @mevaqesh And asking if they do relate to Judaism is perfectly acceptable. The answer could be no. Eg. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22158/759

Comment: It is the current minhag in Eretz Yisrael that the parents of both sides contribute towards buying an apartment for the young couple. As an example see what many of the meshulachim who come to the United States for donations are asking. This sounds like another way of allowing the parents to afford the apartment that they are buying for the chasan  and kallah.

Comment: @mevaqesh What's wrong with everything about Judaism goes? The standard is Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA The issue is whether I can ask whether something is Jewish with so little reason to assume that it is, that the question isnt really justified. I don't know if there is any standard about the degree of justification for questions. If not, then I suppose, not.